# $X^\prime$ or $X^*$ as a symbol for the dual space?

Tags: functional-analysis, notation, dual-spaces

At the moment I am preparing my doctoral thesis and writing down results I have already obtained so that I can use them later. In the process, I have found myself using both the notation $X^*$ and $X'$ for the continuous dual space of normalized spaces, depending on which literature I am currently working with. I realize that I should settle on one notation. But which is the better one?

According to Wikipedia and most of the literature I use, $X^*$ denotes the algebraic dual space and $X'$ denotes the continuous dual space. However, I also find many books where the continuous dual space is denoted by $X^*$.

I tend (for aesthetic reasons) to use the notation $X'$. But then wouldn't it be appropriate to write weak' convergence and $x_n'\rightharpoonup'x'$ instead of weak* convergence and $x_n^*\rightharpoonup^*x^*$?  However, this seems to me to be extremely unusual. Is there a standard work that I can use as a guide?

Comment: Use $X'$, not because it's better, but because you seem to prefer it. As you said yourself, both notations are used, so as long as you clarify what your notation means, neither choice is a bad choice.

Comment: @Theo. Would it then also be legitimate to rename the weak* convergence? Or should I not do that to the reviewers?

Comment: I wouldn't; weak$^*$ convergence is, as far as I'm aware, the standard term. I don't think it's a problem to denote the dual $X'$, but refer to weak$^*$ convergence. This is all stuff I would ask your supervisor though.

Comment: In LaTeX, I would suggest that you write `X\dualspace`. Then, you can decide at any time which notation is used.

Comment: related https://mathoverflow.net/questions/259646/notations-for-dual-spaces-and-dual-operators